# Is there anyway to calculate the integral of a trace?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, matrix, integral, gradient

I would like to calculate the integral of a scalar function as follows:

$$f(x)=\mathrm{tr}((\mathbf{A}x+\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{B}),$$

where $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are two $n\times n$ positive-definite matrices.

Actually, it is an adjusted score (first order derivation) of the log determinant term of a multivariate normal distribution. The raw question is to find the root of

$$f(\sigma^2) = -\mathrm{tr}((\beta^2\mathbf{\Sigma_1}+\mathbf{\Sigma_2}+\sigma^2\mathbf{I_n})^{-1}\mathbf{\Sigma_1})+\mathbf{y}^\mathbf{T}(\beta^2\mathbf{\Sigma_1}+\mathbf{\Sigma_2}+\sigma^2\mathbf{I_n})^{-1}\mathbf{\Sigma_1}(\beta^2\mathbf{\Sigma_1}+\mathbf{\Sigma_2}+\sigma^2\mathbf{I_n})^{-1}\mathbf{y}.$$
I have tried to use `uniroot` in R and fixed-point algorithm to find the root but the two methods are not stable. Therefore, I want to calculate the integral/antiderivate of $f(\sigma^2)$ and find the maximum of the integral/antiderivate:

$$\int f(x)dx\ \mathrm{or}\ \int f(\sigma^2)d\sigma^2,$$

where $x, \sigma^2\in\mathbb{R}^+$ are scalars.

Does anyone know how to find the integral/antiderivate of $f(x)$ or $f(\sigma^2)$? Thanks.

Comment: This is unclear. Can you please write out explicitely the integral you want?

Comment: Thank you for comment, I've edited my question.

Comment: for $f(x)$ to give meaning, $x$ must be some matrix. To which space of matrices do $x$ belong?

Comment: $x$ is a scalar in $\mathbb{R}$, and in this case, I think $x\mapsto f(x)$ still make sense, $\mathbf{A}x$ is the matrix of every element in $\mathbf{A}$ multiplied by x, whereas $f(\sigma^2)$ is the same.

Comment: The problem with the indefinite integral is that it will or will not exist depending on the range of integration.  The approach of maximizing the integral is unlikely to be effective and certainly will not improve anything about `uniroot` that might be "unstable," whatever that might mean.  This leads me to suspect you ought to reformulate this post to ask whatever the underlying statistical question might be.

Comment: It sounds to me like the problem you're trying to solve is 
`<X>`, and you're wondering if `<Y>` is a good way to go 
about it. Is that fair? Because if your real question
is "`<X>`?" then I would suggest only asking about that. As 
its written right now, the question appears to be an 
[XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).